# Create table in excel - Python openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Is there a way to create a table based on all rows and columns which cointain data? Normally a table is created by putting in a fixed reference (eg: *ref="A1:E5")*) What I need is the script to find the last row on the sheet and use this as the reference. This is because the sheet I need to edit contain different amount of rows each time and if I set a fixed reference it will include empty rows in the table.

If have this as a macro in excel but want to convert this to python with openpyxl

Excel Macro

```
Sub A2_SelectAllMakeTable()
lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lrow, lCol)), ,        xlYes).Name = "Masterdata"
End Sub
```

python code start:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('export1.XLSX')
ws1 = wb["Sheet1"]
ws1.title = "Masterdata"
```

Comment: "_create a table based on all rows and columns which cointain data_" - what does this mean? please [edit] your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to use a string as parameter but unsuccessful als I do not get the value in the right format. max = ws1.max_row
value = "AG" + max

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `get_column_letter`, `max_column`, and `max_row` on your worksheet `sheet`, like so:

```
from openpyxl.worksheet.table import Table
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

table = Table(displayName="Table1", ref="A1:" + get_column_letter(sheet.max_column) + str(sheet.max_row))

sheet.add_table(table)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create table like this -

```
tab = Table(displayName="Table1", ref="A1:E5")

# Add a default style with striped rows and banded columns
style = TableStyleInfo(name="TableStyleMedium9", showFirstColumn=False,
                       showLastColumn=False, showRowStripes=True, showColumnStripes=True)
tab.tableStyleInfo = style
ws1.add_table(tab)
```

Example from official Doc - https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/worksheet_tables.html

Comment: Thank you for the quick response but unfortunately my questions in mostly about the reference. Now it only takes A1:E5 but as I have in my macro it needs to take the maximum value of the row and column that contain data.